# will do_shortcode() allow me to run shortcode in content before a line in the template?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

G'day folks, I'm attempting to integrate [Ajax Availability Calendar](http://www.ajaxavailabilitycalendar.com/implementation) into a WordPress site via PHP.

I have multiple calendars set up, and need to display a different one on each property page.

The problem I'm having is that **I need to be able to specify the ID e.g. `$_GET["id_item"]=2` of the calendar before the `<?php require_once 'pathtofile' ?>` statement which is in the template.**

The result I need to achieve is...

```
<?php $_GET["id_item"]=2; require_once 'path\to\required.file'; ?>
```

If I put this code in the template with the appropriate ID, it works, but I need the ID number to change on each page, otherwise I'll always be displaying the calendar with ID number 2.

I currently have custom shortcode (below) with which I can specify the ID in the page content, but I am at a loss as to how to access that ID *before* the statement in the template.

So what I currently have is...

**In Functions.php**

```
function ajaxcalendar_shortcode($atts) {
    $args = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'id_item' => 1
        ), 
        $atts
    );
return '<?php $_GET["id_item"]='.$id_item.'; ?>';
}
add_shortcode('cal_display', 'ajaxcalendar_shortcode');
```

with **the shortcode** `[cal_display id_item = "2"]` **in the content.**

Is it even possible to do this or should I try another approach?
My research suggests that I may be able to use `do_shortcode()` to achieve this, but I haven't figured out how to use it in this situation, or I may be misinterpreting it's purpose.

I've tried putting this **in the page template file:**

```
 <?php $content = the_content(); echo do_shortcode($the_content); ?>
 <?php require_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\MooreRiver\availability\ac-includes\cal.inc.php'; ?>
```

But it continues to display the calendar with ID 1.

Any tips would be appreciated :)

Comment: [cal_display id_item = "2"] in the content is possible and will work fine in your case.
PS: i would suggest you to use shortcode_atts instead of extract though. take a look at this link for reason http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99603/what-does-extract-shortcode-atts-array-do

Comment: The shortcode works fine, that isn't the issue. The issue is that is doesn't achieve the desired result because it isn't executed before the require_once statement which is in the template. Thanks for the link I'll check it out.

Comment: @Yamu Forgot to tag.. I have changed my code to not use extract, I wonder why every tutorial I came across used it if it's been depreciated so long? lol